# Teams App not picking up env variables from .env.teamsfx.local while running locally, process.env is an empty object

Tags: environment-variables, create-react-app, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Teams App not picking up env variables from `.env.teamsfx.local` (files generated automatically by toolkit) while running locally, `process.env` is an empty object.
Below are the scripts from package.json:

```
"start": "env-cmd --silent -f .env.teamsfx.local react-scripts start",
"build": "env-cmd --silent -f .env.teamsfx.local react-scripts build",
```

This works when I create a new .env file but does not pickup env variables from `.env.teamsfx.local` file.

Note: `package.json` and env files are in the same directory i.e root directory

Comment: Could you please share the document you have followed or the repro steps?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - I have teams react app on the azure. I use teams toolkit for configuring and getting env variables. When I am running the application via debug & run command of vscode editor, the app is running on local host but it is not interactive, unable to edit any information
Because I don't get env while running app locally
I'm doing a console log with "process.env", it's an empty object.
This is the script which I am using to start: "start": "env-cmd --silent -f .env.teamsfx.local react-scripts start"

 If I create an  .env file & manually add all variables, then its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you start your react app? Just run `npm run start` and I believe the env variables from `.env.teamsfx.local` will be injected into the process.

Comment: We are using debug and run option (Chrome) from Vs studio code to run the react app.  This is the script which is written in package.json "start": "env-cmd --silent -f .env.teamsfx.local react-scripts start",

Comment: If there is a `dev:teamsfx` script in your `package.json` and how it looks like?

Comment: Yes these are the scripts from package.json:

  "start": "env-cmd --verbose -f .env.teamsfx.local react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd --silent -f .env.teamsfx.local react-scripts build",
      "build:teamsfx": "cross-env-shell \"env-cmd -f .env.teamsfx.${TEAMS_FX_ENV} npm run build\"",
        "build:teamsfx:dev": "cross-env TEAMS_FX_ENV=dev npm run build:teamsfx",

Comment: Seems no `dev:teamsfx`? And how the command of "Start Frontend" task in `.vscode/tasks.json`?

Comment: This is the command for Start Frontend vscode/tasks.json:     
`   {
            "label": "Start Frontend",
            "dependsOn": [
                "teamsfx: frontend start"
            ],
            "dependsOrder": "parallel"
        }, `

Comment: For dev:teamsfx should I try adding this: `"dev:teamsfx": "env-cmd --silent -f .env.teamsfx.local npm run dev"`

Comment: Oh, I see. Your project is not up-to-date. You can follow the steps to solve your problem: 1. Add a script `"dev:teamsfx": "env-cmd --silent -f .env.teamsfx.local npm run start"` in `package.json`. 2. Update the "Start Frontend" task like this: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/blob/dev/hello-world-tab/.vscode/tasks.json#L35-L44.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Kuojian, Should I just copy `Start Frontend task` or any other tasks as well?
When I just copied `start frontend task` and the added the script for `dev:teamsfx` and did a debug and run, start frontend task kept running and the browser never came up with the application

Comment: You are welcome. I recommend you copy all contents from `.vscode/tasks.json` and `.vscode/launch.json`, then try debugging again. Remember to backup your original files in case any error happens.